# Process works where transform does not

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to hit a REST endpoint on Camel and convert that data into a class (and for simplicity and testing convert that class into a JSON string) and make a POST to a local server. I can get it to do all but make that final post and just seems to hang.

App:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    /**
     * A main method to start this application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @Component
    public class RestTest extends RouteBuilder {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            restConfiguration().component("restlet").host("localhost").port(8000).bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json);

            rest("/test").enableCORS(true)
                    .post("/post").type(User.class).to("direct:transform");

            from("direct:transform")
                    .transform().method("Test", "alter")
                    .to("http4:/localhost:8088/ws/v1/camel");
        }
    }

}
```

Bean:

```
@Component("Test")
public class Test {
    public void alter (Exchange exchange) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        User body = exchange.getIn().getBody(User.class);

        try {
            String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(body);

            exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(HttpMethods.POST));
            exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            exchange.getOut().setBody(jsonInString);

        } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

User:

```
public class User {
    @JsonProperty
    private String firstName;

    @JsonProperty
    private String lastName;

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Able to get it to work with process instead of transform but errors when a response is sent back to Camel from the POST:

```
from("direct:transform")
                    .process(new Processor() {
                        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

                            User body = exchange.getIn().getBody(User.class);

                            try {
                                String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(body);

                                exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(HttpMethods.POST));
                                exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
                                exchange.getOut().setBody(jsonInString);

                            } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .to("http4://0.0.0.0:8088/ws/v1/camel");
```

Error

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.apache.camel.converter.stream.CachedOutputStream$WrappedInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:284)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.mappingException(SerializerProvider.java:1110)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportMappingProblem(SerializerProvider.java:1135)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:69)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:32)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:292)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1429)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter._configAndWriteValue(ObjectWriter.java:1158)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:988)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jackson.JacksonDataFormat.marshal(JacksonDataFormat.java:155)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MarshalProcessor.process(MarshalProcessor.java:69)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MarshalProcessor.process(MarshalProcessor.java:50)
    at org.apache.camel.component.rest.RestConsumerBindingProcessor$RestConsumerBindingMarshalOnCompletion.onAfterRoute(RestConsumerBindingProcessor.java:363)
    at org.apache.camel.util.UnitOfWorkHelper.afterRouteSynchronizations(UnitOfWorkHelper.java:154)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultUnitOfWork.afterRoute(DefaultUnitOfWork.java:278)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor$RouteLifecycleAdvice.after(CamelInternalProcessor.java:317)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor$InternalCallback.done(CamelInternalProcessor.java:246)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:109)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97)
    at org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletConsumer$1.handle(RestletConsumer.java:68)
    at org.apache.camel.component.restlet.MethodBasedRouter.handle(MethodBasedRouter.java:54)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.doHandle(Router.java:422)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.handle(Router.java:639)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.doHandle(Router.java:422)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.handle(Router.java:639)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)
    at org.restlet.engine.application.StatusFilter.doHandle(StatusFilter.java:140)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197)
    at org.restlet.engine.CompositeHelper.handle(CompositeHelper.java:202)
    at org.restlet.Component.handle(Component.java:408)
    at org.restlet.Server.handle(Server.java:507)
    at org.restlet.engine.connector.ServerHelper.handle(ServerHelper.java:63)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpServerHelper.handle(HttpServerHelper.java:143)
    at org.restlet.engine.connector.HttpServerHelper$1.handle(HttpServerHelper.java:64)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
    at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:83)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:82)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:647)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Leading to the question of what is the fundamental difference between process and transform?

Comment: Why are you setting the exchange.getOut configuration?  You can use exchange.getIn.

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti `getIn` causes the processor to run multiple times and not make the post request.

Comment: That should not happen, you might to set bridgeEndpoint=true on your http4 endpoint otherwise the http headers from your producer and consumer might get mixed. It should work with exchange.getIn. You can see something similar here https://github.com/SoucianceEqdamRashti/Integration/blob/master/CamelDemo/src/main/java/org/souciance/integration/http/RedirectHTTP.java

Answer (score 0):

A "Processor" in camel is the lowest level message processing primitive. Under the covers a transform definition is executed as a `org.apache.camel.processor.TransformProcessor` which is itself a processor. In fact mostly everything is a Processor under the hood so strictly anything you can accomplish with transform you can accomplish with a pure processor:

Your last error is because you need to unmarshal the output of your HTTP call to an object, before it can be marshalled back to JSON using Jackson. Something like that:

```
from("direct:transform")
  .transform().method("Test", "alter")
  .to("http4:/localhost:8088/ws/v1/camel")
  .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, User.class);
```

Comment: Using a transform gives me the same results as using `getIn` instead of `getOut`. It runs the `alter` method 11 times (yes, 11 every time) just hangs when it gets to the `to` and never resolves. `Unable to run the following server-side task: sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange`